# Showing DoubleProperty up to two decimal places in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a problem showing a doubleProperty up until the second decimal.

A rough layout looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    private TableView<myType> myTable;
    private TableColumn<myType, Double> myCol;

public class myObject {
    .....
    DoubleProperty myDouble;
    ....

    public doubleProperty getPropertyMyDouble() {
        return myDouble;
    }

    public void setMyDouble(double d) {
        myDouble.set(d)
    }
}
```

And I fill the column with:

```
   ...
   myCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->cellData.getValue().getPropertyMyDouble().asObject());
   ...
```

Now my problem is this: If I leave the `setMyDouble` method the way it is, `myCol` is full of numbers with 
lots of decimals. I only want up to the second decimal.

What I tried doing is something like this:

```
public void setMyDouble(double d) {
        BigDecimal bd = new SimpleDecimalFormat("#.00")
        myDouble.set(Double.parseDouble(bd.format(d));
    }
```

Now this works in removing digits after the second decimal, but the problem is that if I have something
like 12.00, because I need to convert to a double at the end (Since `.set()` takes a double) it turns 12.00 
into a 12.0. However, I need to keep two decimal places all the time.

Is there any way to keep `myDouble` as a `DoubleProperty` (I'm doing this because it makes updating the table automatically after changes much easier) 
but present the data as in the `"#.##"` format?

I was thinking maybe doing something like adding an instance variable:

```
StringProperty myDoublePresent;
```

which would just take `myDouble` and turn it into a string and then present in the `"#.##"` format.

But I'd prefer a method where I can work directly with the `DoubleProperty.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
myCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->
     Bindings.format("%.2f", cellData.getValue().getPropertyMyDouble()));
```

Comment: OH MAN you're a lifesaver.

Thank you.

Only minor change needed is myCol has to change to a `TableColumn<myType, String>`

Comment: Yep you are right but if you need to keep it as double in tablecolumn, you should to use cellfactory instead of cellvaluefactory. And in the custom tablecell do the formatting.

Comment: I just converted to a `string`, so I do no calculations with that number anyway.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I would strongly recommend keeping the data type intact and using a `cellFactory` to change the way it is displayed.

Comment: @James_D I'd agree. I've created an answer using this approach. There doesn't appear to be any libraries out there that do this already, which is a shame...

Comment: This unfortunately breaks sorting and makes it alphabetical order instead numeric.

Answer (score 3):

Following James_D suggestion in the accepted answer here is the general purpose solution allowing formatting of any column.

```
public class DecimalColumnFactory<S, T extends Number> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> {

    private DecimalFormat format;

    public DecimalColumnFactory(DecimalFormat format) {
        super();
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> param) {
        return new TableCell<S, T>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                if (!empty && item != null) {
                    setText(format.format(item.doubleValue()));
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

this can be used by

```
theColumn.setCellFactory(new DecimalColumnFactory<>(new DecimalFormat("0.00")));
```