# Get the absolute(int) value of a DoubleProperty in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, gauge

I am having a hard time trying to print the abs value of a DoubleProperty in a Text/Label using bind... Its a gauge, and i want to print the needle angle value in the text/label, but since it is a double property, it prints a double. Here is a sample:

```
needleValue = svg1Rotate.angleProperty();
value.textProperty().bind(needleValue.asString());
```

Funny thing is that in Sys.Out it works like a charm when i use NumberFormat. Like this:

```
        System.out.println(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(needleValue.getValue()));
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Just to clear up terminology, what do you want to show for negative numbers?

Comment: Its a 0 to 100 gauge sir.

Comment: [Try this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString-java.lang.String-) .   FYI, absolute value kind of means changing a negative to a positive.  You want rounded to an integer or, possibly, truncated.

Comment: Use Bindings.format(). An [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318989/showing-doubleproperty-up-to-two-decimal-places-in-tableview/31319235#31319235)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a converter and use it in the binding. In the converter you can create whatever representation you like, even calculate an absolute value before you convert the value to string.

Example:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();

        DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty(12.345);

        TextField valueTextField = new TextField();

        Bindings.bindBidirectional(valueTextField.textProperty(), value, new IntegerStringConverter());

        root.getChildren().addAll(valueTextField);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 310, 200));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public class IntegerStringConverter extends StringConverter<Number> {

        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();

        @Override
        public String toString(Number value) {

            return formatter.format(value);

        }

        @Override
        public Number fromString(String text) {

            try {

                return formatter.parse(text);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```